# Limit to add one post per category only

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

What is the best way to implement a site that has one post per category only?

The structure of the site is that it has an "About", "Services", "Bio" etc.

Per custom post types or per categories?

Comment: Are you sure that [pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) might not be better suited?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, I guess. You should use pages, if there should be only one and not categories.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is category-wise; I usually use this

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $posts = get_posts('category_name=['the category name(slug)']&orderby=rand&numberposts=1'); foreach($posts as $post)  ?>
```